# Jquery expand/collapse inside c:foreach

Tags: jquery

I have a table with two columns. Against a single value of first column, there are multiple values for second column, so using +/- expand/collapse jquery functionality. The problem is jquery is not working inside foreach loop for second column.It's working for first column because there is single +/- for the whole list. 
JSP:

```
    <div class="accordion_container">
    <table>
<tr><td>
            <div class="accordion_h">First Column<span class="plusminus1">+</span></div></td></tr>
<div class="accordion_b" style="display: none;">
<c:foreach var="first" items="firstmap">
<tr>
<td>

<c:out value="${first.value}">

</td>
<td>
<div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
<c:foreach var="sec" items="secmap">
<tr>
<td>
            <div class="accordion_head">SecondColumn<span class="plusminus">+</span></div></td>
<td>

<c:out value="${sec.value}">

</td>
</td>
</tr></c:foreach>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //toggle the component with class accordion_body
    $(".accordion_head").click(function(){
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
        }
        if( $(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')){
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
        }else {
            $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300); 
            $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.accordion_container {
    width: 500px;
}
.accordion_head {
    background-color:skyblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion_body {
    background: lightgray;
}
.accordion_body p{
    padding: 18px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.plusminus{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: The class for your two plus signs are different between the two.

Comment: Yes, I have used different classes. The outer one is working perfectly fine and has the same code as written here with different class ids.  Problem is with the inner Column where foreach is used.